# Monte Carlo Integration Method

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, monte-carlo

$$q = \int_{-1}^{\infty} xe^{-x-1}\sin{x} \,dx$$

How can I use the Monte Carlo integration method to find out the estimate of q and its standard error, using n iid samples generated from Exp(1) ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @OliverDiaz May I ask why did you transform the limits from -1 , inf to 0, inf? What's the theory behind it?

Comment: @OliverDiaz  Thanks a lot! But what should I do with the sin x term in the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion

Using $u=x+1$ gives

$$ q=\int^\infty_{-1}x e^{-(x+1)}\sin(x)\,dx =\int^\infty_0(x-1)e^{-x}\sin(x-1)\,dx$$

Try
$$\hat{q}_n=\Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}(X_k-1)\sin(X_k-1)\Big)$$
as an estimate for $q$, and
$$
\frac{1}{n-1}\sum^n_{k=1}((X_k-1)\sin(X_k-1)-\hat{q}_n)^2
$$
as an estimate of its variance. If you do the whole integration by parts (or do some numerical integration other than MC), the variance can be estimated by
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}((X_k-1)\sin(X_k-1)-q)^2
$$

Here us an short R code:

```
N <- 100
x<- rexp(100000)

q.true <- ntegrate(function(x){(x-1)*sin(x-1)*exp(-x)},
                   lower = 0,upper = Inf)$value
q <-numeric(length = N)
sq <-numeric(length = N)
for(n in 1:N){
  p <- x[1:(n*1000)]
  q[n] <- mean((p-1)*sin(p-1))
  sq[n] <- sum( ((p-1)*sin(p-1) - q[n])^2)/(n*1000 -1)
}


data.frame(n=(1:100)*1000,q_n=q,sn = sq, true_q = q.true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!